# How to display a javascript File object in Chrome's PDF viewer with its name?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, iframe, jspdf, pdf-viewer

I've got a PDF file in the form of a [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/Blob) object (generated with [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF)), that I want to display in an `<iframe>` element.

I can do that easily this way:

```
iframe.src = URL.createObjectURL( blob )
```

The PDF is rendered correctly but I get an esoteric string in place of its name (see image below of Chrome's PDF viewer).

So I tried to convert the Blob to a [File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) object in order to give it a human-readable name.

```
var file = new File( [blob], 'a_name.pdf', { type: 'application/pdf' } )
iframe.src = URL.createObjectURL( file )
```

It works with Firefox: the name is kept when saving the file from the header's PDF viewer.
Unfortunately it is dropped in Chrome and replaced with a random file name before being loaded in the PDF viewer.

Do you know if it is possible to display the PDF File object in the `<iframe>` with its file name?

[image: Chrome's PDF viewer]

Comment: Feeling to lazy to give you a proper answer, But the solution is `Service Workers` You can respond with a custom response and add content-disposition header... but it requires https and are somewhat complicated to set up

Comment: @Supersharp, Any luck on this?

Comment: @AbhishekPrakash, no unless the Endless' solution... or using pdf.js instead.

Comment: Do you have to use an iframe ?

Comment: Is your frame coming from the same domain or no?

Comment: I create the iframe myself. It's coming from nowhere...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can set the title of the PDF generated by [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF) with the `setProperties` method:

```
var doc = new jsPDF();
doc.setProperties({
    title: "This is my title"
});
...
```

That title will be displayed in the PDF viewer in Chrome. You can test it in the [Live Demo](http://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/) page.

Comment: download name of that file still is the same

Comment: Is it possible to change file name without using jsPDF ?

Comment: @AnkitPrajapati - I don't know. The question was asked specifically for jsPDF.