# Suggesting a filename, when saving the PDF displayed in the browser

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, google-chrome, pdf

We are working on an application which uses Angular JS as the front end technology.

The problem we are facing is, we are displaying a PDF directly into the browser in Base64 format.

Now when user saves that opened file which is being opened using JS into the new tab. The file save dialog shows download as the file name for the data to be saved.

I want to overwrite this default behavior. Is it possible using JS?

Any leads to the solution is highly appreciated.

**NOTE:** Here can not use `download` attribute of `a` tag as it is upto the user that whether (s)he wants to save the file into local machine or not.

**NOTE:** [This Answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40657964/how-to-display-a-javascript-file-object-in-chromes-pdf-viewer-with-its-name) Did not help, as it uses jsPDF which in my case we are not using.
Secondly, I want the filname to be prefilled on save file prompt box not in the browser window title.